Issues with OutboxRecord Timeouts and Large TransportOperations Column
We are experiencing intermittent timeouts with our OutboxRecord tables across several hosts. These timeouts occur outside of high-load or batch processing periods, which leads us to suspect that they might be related to either high volumes of records or potential database locking issues.
we have identified that the TransportOperations column in the OutboxRecord table can become extremely large, leading to significant performance issues.
Specifically, we are considering:
Compression: Implementing compression for the TransportOperations column to reduce size and improve performance.
Outbox Feature Configuration: Verifying and optimizing our configuration for the Outbox feature in NServiceBus V 7.X
Could anyone provide guidance or best practices on:
Efficiently handling large data in the TransportOperations column?
Best practices for diagnosing and resolving database locking or timeout issues related to NServiceBus?
Recommendations for using compression for large TransportOperations data using custom behaviour and how?

The best way to optimize Outbox storage is to not have large messages, because databases generally aren't optimized for high I/O of large blobs of data. This can be done using the Claim Check pattern, either by using the NServiceBus Data Bus feature, or manually in a message by taking the "large data" and putting it somewhere else (File share, cloud blob storage) and then including the location/URL of the large data in the message.
There's more discussion on these topics on the NServiceBus forums.

Thank you for the suggestion! In our case, the message content itself isn't particularly large. The issue arises when processing a large number of messages during deduplication—this causes the TransportOperation to become large.
Would it be possible to override IOutboxStorage.Get and Store so that we can modify the data handling to suit our needs? If so, could you provide some guidance on how to go about doing that?

Perhaps you should open a support case showing SQL Profiler screenshots of the database load.
